# Can not use nuxt-i18n (version 5.4.2)

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

In my Nuxt.js application, I want to use the newest version (5.4.2) of [nuxt-i18n](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/). I used it previously without any problems, but I do not understand what is going wrong now:

#### Version

[v5.4.2](https://github.com/nuxt-i18n/releases/tag/v5.4.2)

#### Reproduction link

https://github.com/begueradj/nuxti18nerror

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Either clone my project and follow the README file instructions
2. Or create the a Nuxt.js project: `yarn create nuxt-app my-project`, then install the plugin: `yarn add nuxt-i18n` , then add it to the configuration file `nuxt.config.js`  as the official documentation says:  `modules: [  ['nuxt-i18n', {    // Options   }] ]`

#### What is expected ?

I expect to launch the server without errors when I run `yarn run dev`. As simple as that.

#### What is actually happening?

When I run `yarn run dev` I am getting this error message:

```
 INFO  Building project

✖ fatal /home/begueradj/nuxti18nerror/node_modules/nuxt-i18n/src/helpers/components.js:1
  Error: Cannot find module 'acorn-walk'
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/begueradj/nuxti18nerror/node_modules/nuxt-i18n/src/helpers/components.js:5:16)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
Nuxt Fatal Error :(
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on the same issue,  my boss solved the problem as soon as I informed him about it:

```
yarn add acorn-walk
```

(I think the solution  is self explanatory)

**Update:**

[This](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n/issues/137) is officially [fixed](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n/commit/19c9f961284e1a5db465978e86c950123ee6ab5c) now.